# Auto close modal widget after 5 seconds

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, widget, modal-popup

I created a modal widget that appears after adding product to cart, it works perfectly .
Now I need to close the modal after 5 seconds.
please help!

Comment: Please update question with code you are using to create popup modal.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(dialog).close();
}, 
5000);
```